# mongo: update subdocument's array

Tags: mongodb, database

I have the following schema:

```
{
_id: objectID('593f8c591aa95154cfebe612'),
name: 'test'
businesses: [
  {
     _id: objectID('5967bd5f1aa9515fd9cdc87f'),
     likes: [objectID('595796811aa9514c862033a1'), objectID('593f8c591ba95154cfebe790')]
   }
   {
    _id: objectID('59579ff91aa9514f600cbba6'),
     likes: [objectID('693f8c554aa95154cfebe146'), objectID('193f8c591ba95154cfeber790')]
  }
    ]
}
```

I need to update "businesses.likes" where businesses._id equal to a center value and where businesses.likes contains certain objectID.

If the objectID exists in the array, I want to remove it.

This is what I have tried and didn't work correctly, because $in is searching in all the subdocuments, instead of the only subdocument where businesses._id = with my value:

```
db.col.update(
    { businesses._id: objectID('5967bd5f1aa9515fd9cdc87f'), 'businesses.likes': {$in: [objectID('193f8c591ba95154cfeber790')]}}, 
    {$pull: {'businesses.$.likes': objectID('193f8c591ba95154cfeber790')}}
)
```

Any ideas how how I can write the query? Keep in mind that businesses.likes from different businesses can have the same objectID's.

Comment: It's not that clear what you are asking here because you are masking values of variables when you really need to be showing them. The main problem I see here ( and it's possibly not your real one ) is that you at least appear to be using the same variable in three places. Instead you need to use "one" for the document and "another" for the array content.

Comment: On your supplied data the correct statement would be `.update({ _id: ObjectId('593f8c591aa95154cfebe612'), 'businesses.likes': ObjectId('193f8c591ba95154cfeber790') }, { $pull: { 'businesses.$.likes': ObjectId('193f8c591ba95154cfeber790') } })` Or in fact any value that matches within the `"businesses"` array for a position, and then the `ObjectId` value supplied to actually `$pull` from `'businesses.$.likes'` at the matched position as indicated by `$`.

Comment: I need to select by businesses._id, not by _id, because each business can have likes from same people, which means same objectID's in the array.

Comment: Does not matter. Point is the only reason it would not be working is because you are sending an incorrect combination of values. As long as `businesses._id` is unique it's okay. If you are using that then "that" would identify the "position" and you need not send any other query parameters.

Comment: I have edited my answer now with the correct values. In your query example you are selecting by businesses.likes, which can be the same for multiple businesses, I want only one business to be affected that I am specifying, not all the businesses that have the same objectID in the array.

Comment: You are not understanding what I am saying. It will only be a mistake on your part. The values you are including in your question are not even valid for `ObjectId`. If you want help then you should paste the real data instead of making something up.\

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer now with real objectID's from my database.